# Вывод старого и нового названия и выполнение действия при смене радио кнопки

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qradiobutton, qbuttongroup

Есть такой небольшой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        self.rb_one = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("One", self.group)
        self.rb_two = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Two", self.group)
        self.rb_thr = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Thr", self.group)
        self.rb_one.setChecked(True)

        self.hLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rb_one)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rb_two)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rb_thr)

        self.vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Есть ли возможность получить такое поведение: 
по умолчанию выбрана кнопка `rb_one`, 
если пользователь выбирает кнопку `rb_two`, то в консоль выводится:

- *`Кнопка изменена с One на Two`*,
- а текст копируется из текстового поля `string = self.text.text()`
- и передается в некую функцию `from_one_to_two(string)`, которая возвращает и пишет новый текст в поле.

Теперь уже выбрана кнопка два (`rb_two`), 
пользователь выбирает кнопку *`Thr`* (`rb_thr`),

- выводится сообщение *`Кнопка изменена с Two на Thr`*,
- текст снова копируется
- и передается уже в функцию `from_two_to_thr()`.

Тоже самое, если он выберет с третьей активной кнопкой вторую, то выведется *`Кнопка изменена с Thr на Two`* 
и вызовется `from_thr_to_two()` и так далее по аналогии все комбинации.

Организовать такое через пушбатон вроде несложно, но как это сделать автоматизировано, по идеи нужно использовать `toggled.connect()`, но как это правильно сделать и возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все возможно. Пробуйте:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text  = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.group  = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()      # QGroupBox()
        self.rb_one = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("One") #, self.group)
        self.rb_two = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Two") #, self.group)
        self.rb_thr = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Thr") #, self.group)
        self.rb_one.setChecked(True)

        self.oldChecked = "One"
        self.newChecked = None
        self.string     = None

        self.group.addButton(self.rb_one)
        self.group.addButton(self.rb_two)
        self.group.addButton(self.rb_thr)
        self.group.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

        self.hLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rb_one)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rb_two)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rb_thr)

        self.vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self.oldChecked != radioButton.text():
            self.newChecked = radioButton.text()
            self.string = "с {} на {}".format(self.oldChecked, self.newChecked)
            self.text.appendPlainText("Кнопка изменена {}".format(self.string)) 
            self.oldChecked = self.newChecked

            self.doSomething(self.string)

    def doSomething(self, t):
        if t == "с One на Two": print(t, ": Делай что-нибудь")
        if t == "с One на Thr": print(t, ": Делай что-нибудь")
        if t == "с Two на One": print(t, ": Делай что-нибудь")
        if t == "с Two на Thr": print(t, ": Делай что-нибудь")
        if t == "с Thr на One": print(t, ": Делай что-нибудь")
        if t == "с Thr на Two": print(t, ": Делай что-нибудь")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]